# Prevent animation of an element in a custom cell when entering and exiting edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell that has an UIImageView in it that I do not want to animate when entering and exiting edit mode. I have gotten it to animate the other direction with the autoresizingMask property, but I am unable to prevent its movement.

I create the custom cell with a class, then use it in the cellForRowInIndexPath method. The UIImageView is part of that class, although the layout is done in cellForRowInIndexPath. I am essentially creating a progress bar that spans across the bottom. So it will span from the left to the right. The animation that I am trying to prevent is when entering edit mode, the image view slides to the right to make space for the delete circle graphic.

Comment: Please include the following details : how you create the custom cell (layout in a nib, in code, dynamic prototypes), whereabouts in the cell your image view is (left, right, top, bottom) and what animation (moving, resizing) you are trying to prevent.

Comment: I create the custom cell with a class, then use it in the cellForRowInIndexPath method. The UIImageView is part of that class, although the layout is done in cellForRowInIndexPath.  I am essentially creating a progress bar that spans across the bottom. So it will span from the left to the right. The animation that I am trying to prevent is when entering edit mode, the image view slides to the right to make space for the delete circle graphic.

Comment: I've added that to your question - that's better than including it in a comment. So I think you're saying that you add the progress bar in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Can you add that code to your question? As my answer says, I think you have the image view added to the content view, but I'd like this confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image view is probably added as a subview of your cell's content view. The content view is resized when the cell enters editing mode, meaning that the image view has to move if it is close to the edge of the content view.

To keep it in the same place it can be added as a subview of the cell directly instead of the cell's content view.

Comment: That did the trick! I changed [self.contentView addSubview:cellBar]; to [self addSubview:cellBar]; and all works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement this code in the tableview delegate:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

This will work if you don't want anything to move on the tableview cell while it enters editing mode. Now if you want to move *some* things then use jrturton answer.